# Comparing data from SQLite database - Android (java)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, type-mismatch

I made a SQLite highscores that has 3 columns; rank(int), score(long) and percentage(int).  I am trying to pull all the data from the columns and compare them to the score the user just got to see if their new score made the highscores list that holds the top 10.

I want the highscores to be prioritized by percentage first and then score to break any ties.  Below is where I am starting to do this.  Am I on the correct track?  I have never used SQLite even outside of Java so this is all brand new to me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
//Check if new record makes the top 10.
public boolean check(int rank, long score, int percentage) {
    //SQL query to get last score/percentage if highscores has 10 records...
    long[] scores = new long[9];
    int[] percentages = new int[9];
    scores = db.execSQL("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";");  //Error:  Type mismatch
    percentages = db.execSQL("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";");  //Error:  Type mismatch
    //Algorithms to compare scores and percentages go here...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 scores = db.execSQL("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";");
```

`execSQL` returns void.

As per [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

You may need to use either [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (or) [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29) mechanisms to do select.